# Batch migrate GroupWise emails to Outlook

Tags: vba, outlook, attachment

I am moving from GroupWise to Outlook 2010...

I am wanting to move all my emails from GroupWise to outlook...

I have forwarded the emails on to my outlook 2010 inbox folder Received.

The problem I have is the original email has been sent as an attachment not as a forward on! so what i have to do is:

1. Extract the attachment and save the email on to my computer drive F:\GWEmails
2. Then drag the email back into my inbox!

its a little tedious when you have over 1000 emails!

What can I do to simplify the process?

Comment: There are some notes here http://wiki.lessthandot.com/index.php/Save_Outlook_Emails that may help.

Answer (score 0):

There are some examples of VBA code saving Outlook emails at http://wiki.lessthandot.com/index.php/Save_Outlook_Emails that may help.

Comment: Bringing Remou's comment down as an answer.